# adding subaggregations in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to retrieve data from Elasticsearch with the following structure:

```
"hits":[
   { _index...
     _type....
     _score...
     "_source": {
                  "language": "english",
                  "timeDic": {
                               "date": "Friday",
                               "time": {
                                         "timeofday": "15:23"
                                        }
                              }
                 }
   }       
   { _index...
     _type....
     _score...
     "_source": {
                  "language": "spanish",
                  "timeDic": {
                               "date": "Friday",
                               "time": {
                                         "timeofday": "18:23"
                                        }
                              }
                 }
   }
   { _index...
     _type....
     _score...
     "_source": {
                  "language": "english",
                  "timeDic": {
                               "date": "Saturday",
                               "time": {
                                         "timeofday": "08:23"
                                        }
                              }
                 }
   }
  ...
 }
]
```

The fields I want to obtain are date and timeofday.

I have tried to obtain the data with the following code.

```
    'timeDic': {
       terms: {
             field: 'date.keyword',
             order: {
                  _count: "desc"
               }
             },
             aggs: {
                  'time': {
                        terms: {
                             field: "timeofday.keyword",
                              order: {
                                   _count: "desc"
                                   }
                          }
                  }
              }
```

The thing is that the bucket of the field hour1 is empty, it returns this:

```
timeDic: {doc_count_error_upper_bound: 0, sum_other_doc_count: 0, 
…}
   buckets: [{key: "Friday", doc_count: 208,…}, {key: "Sunday", 
   doc_count: 207,…},…]
     0: {key: "Friday", doc_count: 208,…}
      doc_count: 208
      key: "Friday"
        time: {doc_count_error_upper_bound: 0, 
         sum_other_doc_count: 0, buckets: []}
            buckets: []
            doc_count_error_upper_bound: 0
            sum_other_doc_count: 0
```

and the answer I'm looking for is something like this.

```
timeDic: {doc_count_error_upper_bound: 0, sum_other_doc_count: 0, 
…}
   buckets: [{key: "Friday", doc_count: 208,…}, {key: "Sunday", 
   doc_count: 207,…},…]
     0: {key: "Friday", doc_count: 208,…}
      doc_count: 208
      key: "Friday"
        time: {doc_count_error_upper_bound: 0, 
         sum_other_doc_count: 0, buckets: []}
            buckets: [key: "15:23", doc_count: whatever they are,…}]
                    doc_count: whatever they are
                    key: "15:23"
                    doc_count_error_upper_bound: 0
                    sum_other_doc_count: 0
```

Of course I have read the Elasticsearch documentation and other comments but so far I have not found anything...

Comment: Hey @Adrain, your mapping looks very confusing, could you please paste a sample document or the mapping information of the part `timDic`. I don't understand the part `"hour1": { "hour2": "15:30" }` you've mentioned in the question. What do you mean by `hour1` and `hour2` over here.

Comment: well yeah.. I understand you I'm going to edit it. The thing is that I have a lot of elements which I have to classify according to dates and time.  I need to know how many elements I have for example on a Tuesday and Friday but also when I know the date, I need to know the how many of them belong to a specific time.

Comment: Got it. Let me see what I can do. I will update my answer in a short while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our discussions, I've come up with the below information which contains sample documents, aggregation query and its response.

### Sample Documents:

```
POST myindex/mydocs/1
{
  "timeDic": {
    "date": "Friday",
    "time": {
      "timeofday": "15:30"
    }
  }
}

POST myindex/mydocs/2
{
  "timeDic": {
    "date": "Friday",
    "time": {
      "timeofday": "15:30"
    }
  }
}

POST myindex/mydocs/3
{
  "timeDic": {
    "date": "Friday",
    "time": {
      "timeofday": "15:45"
    }
  }
}

POST myindex/mydocs/4
{
  "timeDic": {
    "date": "Monday",
    "time": {
      "timeofday": "15:30"
    }
  }
}
```

### Aggregation Query:

*Solution for what `times` along with its `count` are available on the dates available.*

```
POST myindex/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs":{
    "timeDic": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "timeDic.date.keyword",
        "min_doc_count": 1, 
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "theTimes": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "timeDic.time.timeofday.keyword",
            "min_doc_count": 1, 
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query would return the list of times for that particular day. You should have exactly seven main buckets, each representing days in week with list of sub-buckets with times of that day.

Its basically a [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) along with another child aggregation which is again a [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

Note how I've added `"min_doc_count": 1` which states that I only want to return buckets having `count > 0`.

Also, you can change the value of size according to your requirements.

### Aggregation Result:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 4,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "theDays" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "Friday",
          "doc_count" : 3,
          "theTimes" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "15:30",
                "doc_count" : 2
              },
              {
                "key" : "15:45",
                "doc_count" : 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "Monday",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "theTimes" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "15:30",
                "doc_count" : 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if this is what you are looking for.